# How to make an oldest/newest post button on top of page?

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm looking to have a "Sort by: Newest | Oldest" link/button on one of my Wordpress pages.

I found this question posted in the Wordpress Forums but it wasn't working for me:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-by-drop-down-with-custom-field-value?replies=29

I was getting an error message with using the whole code. When I take out the last chunk it appears properly on the page but when I select "oldest", for example, the page refreshes and doesn't sort the oldest to newest. This is the part I took out because I was getting an error message (I'm guessing this is the part that does the actual work):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string . $order); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

This is all the code in the template (it includes the new code from the link * but won't work because of something with the last chunk):

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49bdade9654f772df7aaa56a4da13223d0d70a93

How do I format this code in order for it to work?

Comment: You need to show us the value of: `$query_string` and `$order`.  Where do those get set? What are their values?

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty new to coding. My experience probably isn't helping at the moment. I'm not sure if this would help but it's for the category called 'Books' (taxonomy=category&tag_ID=26&post_type=post)
And the page is using the template in the 2nd link. I'd like to be able to order them by publish date (newest to oldest, or oldest to newest) and by title (A-Z).